# jQuery's .prev on numerous divs with a 'click' event handler?

Tags: jquery

I've simplified my problem in the code below, but I'm having trouble getting `.prev` to work the way I need it to in my example below. It is only grabbing the first value, and not the value corresponding to where the `<button>` is located.

Any help?

```
<h1>-</h1>

<div>
  <input type='hidden' value="value_1">
  <button class="delete">1</button>
</div>

<div>
  <input type='hidden' value="value_2">
  <button class="delete">2</button>
</div>

<div>
  <input type='hidden' value="value_3">
  <button class="delete">3</button>
</div>
```

And my JS:

```
var value = $('.delete').prev('input[type=hidden]').attr('value');

$('.delete').click(function() {
  $('h1').text(value);
});
```

[Non-working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motioncrafter/5dcrae3d)

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the previous element of the *clicked* element. In the `click` event handler, `this` refers to the clicked `.delete` element, therefore use `$(this).prev('input[type=hidden]')`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/e5uk602y/)

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
  var value = $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').attr('value');
  $('h1').text(value);
});
```

When you were using `$('.delete').prev('input[type=hidden]').attr('value')` outside of the `click` event handler, you were getting the `value` attribute of the *first* matched element.